# Как загрузить файл в контроллер через Ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring-boot

Изучаю Java. Дошла учеба до Web.

Решил сделать добавление объекта через модальное окно, а не через новую страницу.
Там нужно использовать Ajax. Как я понял, всю форму нагуглил, как загружать, а как передать файл в контроллер, так и не понял.

Контроллер:

```
@PostMapping("/createCandidate")
public String createCandidate(
    @RequestBody Candidate candidate,  
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) throws IOException {
    candidate.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
    this.store.create(candidate);
    return PATS;
}
```

Форма:

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="visible">
        <label for="visible">Publish</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
    function send_candidate() {
        let moreinfo = '';

        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            moreinfo = this.checked;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/createCandidate",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: $("#id").val(),
                name: $("#name").val(),
                desc: $("#desc").val(),
                visible: $("#visible").val().Boolean = Boolean(moreinfo)
            })
        })
    }
</script>
```

Модель:

```
public class Candidate {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] photo;
    private boolean visible;
    private String desc;
    private LocalDateTime created;
}
```

Comment: написал ответ. Старался подробно все описать. Если что-то будет непонятно - спрашивайте (под ответом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Backend

Начнем с контроллера:

```
@PostMapping("/createCandidate")
public String createCandidate(
    @RequestBody Candidate candidate,  
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) throws IOException {
    candidate.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
    this.store.create(candidate);
    return PATS;
}
```

Здесь вы последовательно пытаетесь получить:

1. `@RequestBody Candidate candidate`
   Который ожидает, что в теле POST-запроса будет сериализованный объект.
   В вашем случае подразумевалось, что вы пришлете POST запрос c заголовком `Content-type: application/json` и c cформированным c помощью JavaScript'а JSON'ом, который будет занимать все тело запроса
2. `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`
   Который подразумевает, что Вы пришлете POST-запрос c заголовком `Content-type: multipart/form-data`, в котором будет часть, посвященная файлу, которая будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary5oVe5Ocv731AlUHT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2022-08-29_06-32.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

Два данных объявления конфликтуют и не могут сосуществовать одновременно.
Один ожидает запрос одного типа, другой - второго.

Нужно выбрать что-то одно: и в вашем случаеь легче выбрать `multipart/form-data`

Соответственно, нам нужно всего лишь понять, как нам можно передать форму типа `multipart/form-data`.
И тут на самом деле все просто: для этого достаточно заменить аннотацию `@RequestBody` на `@ModelAttribute`

```
@PostMapping("/createCandidate")
public String createCandidate(
        @ModelAttribute Candidate candidate,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) throws IOException {
   // ...
}
```

Также для корректной последующей отдачи изображений во время их запросов, было бы неплохо еще сохранять:

- `Content-type` или тип изображения (`image/jpeg`,image/png` и пр)
- Размер изображения
  Для того, чтобы позже можно было указать их в заголовках ответа, отдающих эти изображения.

Поэтому добавим в модель поля:

```
private Long size;
private String contentType;
```

ну и раз уж мы залезли в модель, то сразу вам скажу, что `desc` очень плохое имя для объекта, который будет маппиться на таблицу БД, потому что `DESC` - это зарезервированное ключевое слово в SQL - оно отвечает за указание направления сортировки

```
select * from users where 1=1 ORDER BY ID DESC; /* <- и это точно не ваше поле*/
```

Поэтому я дожидаться беды не стал и сразу переименовал его в

```
private String description;
```

Оно так и понятнее.

Кстати, раз уж мы договорились о БД, то сразу скажу, что тип колонки BLOB, не такой уж и большой (у меня во всяком случае изображения не помещаются) и я его создавал как LONGBLOB

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "photo", columnDefinition="LONGBLOB")
private byte[] photo;
```

**Для справки:**

```
TINYBLOB:   <           255 байт
BLOB:       <        65 535 байт
MEDIUMBLOB: <    16 777 215 байт
LONGBLOB:   < 4 294 967 295 байт
```

Итого модель:

```
public class Candidate {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] photo;
    private boolean visible;
    private String description; // <- его мы переименовали
    private Long size;          // <- а вот этих двух товарищей
    private String contentType; // <- мы добавили, чтобы корректно 
                                //    отдавать http ответ с изображением
    private LocalDateTime created;
}
```

После таких приготовлений мы можем в контроллере прокинуть данные из `MultipartFile file` в `Candidate candidate` следующим образом:

```
candidate.setPhoto(file.getBytes());
candidate.setContentType(file.getContentType());
candidate.setSize(file.getSize());
```

В итоге метод будет выглядеть так

```
@PostMapping("/createCandidate")
public String createCandidate(
        @ModelAttribute Candidate candidate,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) throws IOException {
    candidate.setPhoto(file.getBytes());
    candidate.setContentType(file.getContentType());
    candidate.setSize(file.getSize());
    candidate.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
    this.store.create(candidate); // за данный метод я не ручаюсь, он под вашей ответственностью
    return PATS;
}
```

#### Frontend

**Для начала:**
оставьте, пожалуйста, jQuery... дайте ему уже умереть спокойно.
Ванильный JavaScript уже давно умеет делать все что нужно:

- запросы легко и просто можно делать с помощью `fetch()`
- искать элементы по CSS-селектору можно с помощью `querySelector()`/`querySelectorAll()`

**шаблон:**
Не забудем, что мы переименовали поле, поэтому на нужно поправить соответствующее поле в форме

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
    </div>
```

Возвращаемся к JavaScript:

Если у нас есть нормально оформленная форма, с корректными именами полей, которые совпадают с именами полей модели - нам необязательно ручками брать и по одному полю извлекать все данные вот так вот:

```
name: $("#name").val(),
```

Можно просто найти элемент формы и передать его в `FormData`

```
let formElement = document.getElementById("data");
let data = new FormData(formElement);
```

а потом его можно будет передать прямиком в `fetch()`;

Но перед этим я покажу Вам как, как найти список элементов по CSS-селектору и проитерировать их без jQuery:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function (element) {
    moreinfo = element.checked;
});
```

`document.querySelectorAll()` выглядит чуть более громоздко чем `$()`, но он есть везде, не требует никаких подключений и работает отлично... и это достаточная цена за то, чтобы не тоскать с одной страницы на другую труп jQuery.

Кстати, в форму можно и ручками что-то добавить если нужно.
Вот так это делается:

```
data.append('visible', moreinfo);
```

##### Запрос

Чтобы сделать нужный нам запрос достаточно сделать:

```
fetch("/createCandidate", {
    method : "POST",
    body: data
})
```

Это асинхронная функция и возвращает она Promise.
Соответственно обработать результаты можно в `then()`

Итого JS получился таким:

```
<script>
    function send_candidate() {
        let moreinfo = '';
        document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function (element) {
            moreinfo = element.checked;
        });
        let formElement = document.getElementById("data");
        let data = new FormData(formElement);
        data.append('visible', moreinfo);
        fetch("/createCandidate", {
            method : "POST",
            body: data
        }).then(response => response.text()) // Если вы возвращаете application/json, то .then(response => response.json())
          .then(html => console.log(html));
    }
</script>
```

#### Что в итоге?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все поля на месте и содержимое фото тоже сохранилось.

---

проверял корректность я с помощью такого метода, который находит в таблице нужную запись и возвращает картинку

```
@GetMapping("/candidate/{id}/photo")
public ResponseEntity<?> photo(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws IOException {
    Optional<Candidate> candidateSearchResult = candidateRepository.findById(id);
    if(!candidateSearchResult.isPresent()) {
        // если не найдено, то выбрасываем 404
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    Candidate candidate = candidateSearchResult.get();
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(candidate.getContentType())) // вот тут нам понадобились Content-Type
            .contentLength(candidate.getSize())                         // и size
            .body(candidate.getPhoto());                                // и в body передаем byte[] photo
}
```

На выходе получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает как надо!

#### Безопасность

Если у Вас подключен Spring Security(и только в этом случае) - не забудьте пробросить CSRF токен в форму

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Иначе Spring Security не авторизует ваш запрос

Comment: Всё предельно ясно. Огромное спасибо за хорошее разъяснение и ваше потраченное время.

Comment: У меня вопрос ещё появился. Как возможно обновить страницу после отправки формы? Что бы обновить данные на странице?

Comment: @Valera, если вы про JS, то `window.location.reload();` в последнем `.then(res -> { window.location.reload(); })`

Comment: }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(html => console.log(html)).then(res => {window.location.reload();});
    }
Что-то не помогло, при добавлении нового элемента приходится обновлять страницу что бы увидеть его на экране.

Comment: }).then(response => response.json()).then(res => {window.location.reload();}); }

Comment: @Valera один then у вас лишний. см комментарий выше

Comment: Я не знаю можно ли тут скриншот кидать, данный код сбрасывает форму только но не обновляет страницу \-----\
prnt.sc/bG4sExaEQSPw  \-----\
prnt.sc/I5t9ex1BCfzg   \-----\
prnt.sc/loJixjiiSz35    \-----\

Comment: @Valera ссылку можно прикрепить со скриншотом

Comment: По скриншотам не особо понятно правильно ли вы все обрабатываете или нет. Может у вас что-то с сохранением?

Comment: Если хотите, можете мне в тг написать позже(он в профиле указан) только я сегодня занят буду и нормально посмотреть смогу только завтра

Comment: Проблема была в контроллере изменил возвращаемый тип \-----\ prnt.sc/WZBMV1zLNfyK \-----\ на prnt.sc/hm9gV9bTYdqd \-----\ и всё заработало. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя AJAX-запрос находится в функции, а в какой момент функция вызывается? При вызове функции у тебя и отправится AJAX на заданный урл: "url: "/createCandidate",". Только убери большую букву из ссылки на бэк - '/createcandidate'.

В этом была проблема?

Comment: не вводите пользователя в заблуждение. Верхний регистр тут не причем. Путь в JS и в контроллере совпадают.

Comment: Зачем создавать пост если вы не знаете ответ?