# TelegramBots Java: Отправка сообщения без update

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

Я хочу создать бота, который после /start будет периодически сам отправлять мне сообщения с результатом выполнения определенного действия без необходимости каждый раз писать ему для получения ответа. Сейчас бот отправляет сообщение только в ответ на моё сообщение. Я хочу чтобы он отправлял сообщение на заданный ChatId, не дожидаясь пока я ему напишу. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: в чем именно сложность возникает?

Comment: в отправке без Update? или в рассылке по расписанию?

Comment: В отправке без update

Comment: `telegramBot.execute(new SendMessage(userId,message));` - вот и все  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Что за объект telegramBot? Откуда его взять?

Comment: в данном случае `com.pengrad.telegrambot`

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api/6.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### com.github.pengrad:java-telegram-bot-api

Добавляем зависимость

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.pengrad</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-telegram-bot-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Отправяем сообщение:

```
// Созаем бота
TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot("BOT_TOKEN");

// Отправляем сообщение
Long chatId = 1234567L;
SendResponse response = bot.execute(new SendMessage(chatId, "Hello!"));
```

#### rubenlagus/TelegramBots

Добавляем зависимость

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
      <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Здесь нам для начала нужно переопределить класс для нашего бота:

```
public  class StackoverflowBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        System.out.println("Тут пишем обработчик событий бота");
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
               // тут пишем username нашего бота
        return "______bot"; 
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
               // а тут наш токен
        return "549*******:AAF******************************";
    }
}
```

Регистрируем нашего бота

```
try {
    TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
    TelegramLongPollingBot  bot = new StackoverflowBot();
    botsApi.registerBot(bot);

} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

И далее можем отправять сообщение:

```
Long chatId = 143195411L;
SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
message.setChatId(chatId.toString());
message.setText("Hello\nfrom StackOverflow");
bot.execute(message);
```

И все вместе:

```
try {
    TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
    TelegramLongPollingBot  bot = new StackoverflowBot();
    botsApi.registerBot(bot);

    Long chatId = 143195411L;
    SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
    message.setChatId(chatId.toString());
    message.setText("Hello\nfrom StackOverflow");
    bot.execute(message);
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

И как результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сорри за ленту.
В боте она длинная и чистить ее долго, а нового бота чисто для вопроса создавать как-то черезчур

Comment: А, эта та вторая библиотека. Я выбирал между ней и rubenlagus/TelegramBots, и выбрал последнюю, чего делать не стоило. Попробую переписать на этой.

Comment: @NikMAX, там тоже все просто...сейчас добавлю

Comment: Да! Получилось! Несколько часов голову ломал, а надо было просто взять другую библиотеку. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да, добавьте для примера. Кому-то в будущем поможет

Comment: @NikMAX Добавил...Пример определения самого бота нужен?

Comment: Если не затруднит, добавьте. Будет отличный пост для новичков

Comment: @NikMAX добавил рабочий пример

Comment: Впервые вижу настолько развернутый ответ. Честно говоря, я в приятном шоке. Вы сделали мой день, ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @NikMAX по моим меркам он еще недостаточно большой и подробный) Но спасибо) Удачного дня!)

Comment: @NikMAX https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1443686/189027 это крайний для примера)